# MYSQL How do I use values stored in a JSON array in Table_1 to pull data from Table_2, then replace the Array in Table_1 with the data from Table_2

Tags: mysql

I want to pull the IDs from the JSON Array `AssignedTo` in `Table_1`
Use that data to pull from `Table_2`
then replace the data in `AssignedTo` in `Table_1` to the names in `Table_2`

```
Table_1
    JobID       Table_2_ID
     101     [403, 404, 405]
     102     [406, 407, 408]
     103     [409, 410, 411]


Table_2 
        personID     FirstName     LastName 
        403          Josh          Adams
        404          Mary          Poppins
        405          Mickey        Mouse
        406          Donald        Duck
        407          Pete          Schmit
        408          Anna          Bagel
        409          Jake          Crabs
        410          Sponge        Bob
        411          Stuart        Little

SELECT JobID, AssignedTo (REPLACE AssignedTo[0-2] WITH 
CONCAT(Table_2.FirstName, ' ', Table_2.LastName 
WHERE Table_1.AssignedTo = Table_2.personID)
FROM Table_1, Table_2
```

Result:

```
JobID   AssignedTo
101     [Josh Adams, Mary Poppins, Micky Mouse]
102     [Donald Duck, Pete Schmit, Anna Bagel]
103     [Jake Crabs, Sponge Bob, Stuart Little]
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough. show table definition and desired result.

Comment: I updated the information. Is it clearer to you now?